# Cloth sim; Cloth Pin and Self Collision making very bad/weird behavior?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make pants, but these two settings I'm trying to use are causing issues with my model.

Here is a gif of my character's pants withOUT self collision:

[image]

As you can see, the cloth simulates alright, but it doesn't self collide (as it shouldnt). The issue here however,  is the cloth pinning (the top ring of vertices at the top of the pants are pinned and parented to the character). If you look at the top area of the pants, near the crotch and waist, the pinning creates some sort of very odd pinching and rippling affect. How can I fix this?

Also, the issue with self collision:

[image]

The clothing doesn't behave properly at all, and either pinches tightly like the gif or explodes.

Here are my settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Posted as an answer below, as I believe it will at least help solve the problem.

Comment: I downloaded your .blend, but I see no cloth in it.  Are you sure you uploaded the correct file?

Comment: this tutorial is pretty good for solving this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem today. After a lot of head scratching I fixed the problem by removing doubles. I had duplicated vertices accidentally while duplicating a mesh in edit mode and the self collision was trying to separate the vertices that were on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working a lot with cloth recently.  I'm no expert, but here are some questions & things to check.

-Your quality for collisions is low.  Higher values will give better results.  3 to 4 is what I usually use for tests, 8 for final sims.  Then bake it.

-Is your human model set as a collision mesh?
It appears it is from the short animation.  Make sure it is not intersecting with the shorts (the shorts aren't crossed inside of the human mesh).  Even leave a little space.  Depending on your values for distance of collision on the collision mesh, too close will cause an interaction.  That may be the problem in the first example, as the calculation has trouble since it is already colliding and inside the collider mesh.

This may also be causing the errors in the self collision example.  Having a cloth mesh cross inside a collider mesh can cause problems throughout the sim.

-Have you applied the scale (Ctrl+A ->Scale).

-Are your normals pointing outward? (Edit mode, select all vertices + Ctrl+N)
That may help as well.

If this doesn't solve your issues, post your blend file and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yep! I've gone through and tried those all. The model still performs very weirdly. I'll edit the main post with the blend.

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem with the link, or what, but I cannot download your blend.  Does the link work to let you (anyone) download it?

Comment: Works for me :s

Comment: It's weird, I've tried downloading this blend file on multiple computers.  Then I tried a Blend file on a different post, and can't download it either.  It opens a blank page.  It's all been here at my work, so maybe a firewall issue?  I don't know.  Sorry, I'll keep trying.

Comment: Huge thanks to GiantCowFilms who had a DoS attack, and had to fix it so I could download the blend.  I downloaded the blend, and there's no shorts that I can find anywhere!  If you can please try again and upload the same blend that you had above so I can see what's wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh woops... I've kinda been ignoring this site ^^' I decided I'd just mesh the pants normally and try sculpting to solve the issue and bypass cloth sim altogether, so I don't have the shorts anymore with the cloth sim :( Sorry about that!